# How to mock fetch when testing a React app?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch, react-testing-library

I would like to test a small React web app where I use the global `fetch` method.

I tried to mock `fetch` in this way:

```js
global.fetch = jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(endpoint =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(mockResponse)
  })
);
```

... but the mock seems to be ignored, while the built-in `fetch` seems to be used: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 ...` looks like a failed call to the built-in `fetch`.

I then tried to use `jest.fn` instead of `jest.spyOn`:

```js
global.fetch = jest.fn(endpoint =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(mockResponse)
  })
);
```

... and was surprised to see a different error. Now the mock seems to be taken into consideration, but at the same time is not working correctly:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

       8 |     this.updateTypes = this.props.updateTypes;
       9 |     this.updateTimeline = this.props.updateTimeline;
    > 10 |     fetch('/timeline/tags')
         |     ^
      11 |       .then(res => res.json())
      12 |       .then(tags => tags.map(tag => <option value={tag} key={tag} />))
      13 |       .then(options => options.sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key)))
```

I find the documentation of Jest and React Testing Library a bit confusing, honestly. What might be the problem with what I am doing?

### Edit

The React component I am trying to test is called "App", was generated with Create React App, and was changed to include a call to `fetch`. I can gladly provide the code for this component, but I believe that the problem lies in the tests.

At the beginning of my `App.test.js` file, I `import React from 'react';`, then `import { render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen } from '@testing-library/react';`, and finally `import App from './App';`. I subsequently attempt to mock `fetch` in one of the ways I described, and then declare the following test:

```js
test('renders a list of items, upon request', async () => {
  const app = render(<App />);

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Update'));

  await waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('list'));

  expect(screen.getByRole('list')).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByRole('list')).toHaveClass('Timeline');
});
```

Finally, I end my test file with `global.fetch.mockRestore();`.

Comment: have you read this? https://kentcdodds.com/blog/stop-mocking-fetch/

Comment: Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. There's something wrong happens with your mocks that cannot be explained with snippets you posted. *but the mock seems to be ignored, while the built-int fetch seems to be used* - it should result in error because JSDOM doesn't provide `fetch`, and calling jest.spyOn on missing property is not allowed. I see no way how *Cannot read property 'then' of undefined* error is possible with second mock alone, unless the error refers to another line which may happen if source maps went wrong.

Comment: @RedBaron FWIW, the article refers to integration and not unit testing and should be treated with caution.

Comment: @EstusFlask I appended more information to my question. If what I added is not enough (for example if I should add the whole code of my `App` component) let me know, and I will edit my question.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it's not enough. I've tried to explain how mocking should be performed. If the answer doesn't help, then the problem is very specific to your project, please, provide a way to reproduce a problem - a repo, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That there's `ECONNREFUSED` error instead of `fetch is not defined` means that `fetch` has been polyfilled. It's not a part of JSDOM and isn't polyfilled by Jest itself but is specific to current setup. In this case the polyfill is provided by create-react-app.

It's always preferable to mock existing global function with `jest.spyOn` and not by assigning them as `global` properties, this allows Jest to do a cleanup. A thing like `global.fetch = jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch')` should never be done because this prevents `fetch` from being restored. This can explain `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error for seemingly correctly mocked function.

A correct and safe way to mock globals is to mock them before each test and restore after each test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockResolvedValue({
    json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockResponse)
  })
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});
```

There should be no other modifications to `global.fetch` in order for a mock to work correctly.

A preferable way to restore mocks and spies is to use [configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#restoremocks-boolean) option instead of `jest.restoreAllMocks` because not doing this may result in accidental test cross-contamination which is never desirable.

Another reason for `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error to appear is that Jest incorrectly points at `fetch` line, and the error actually refers to another line. This can happen if source maps don't work correctly. If `fetch` is mocked correctly and there are other `then` in the same component, it's a plausible explanation for the error.

Comment: Thank you for the rich answer. The problem with my test turned out to be a beginner's mistake: I was not using `beforeEach` and `afterEach`.