# How to mock fetch call inside of child´s componentDidMount with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I hope you will be able to help me, I tried to find the answer but was not successfull with my specific problem.

I need to test with Jest/Enzyme if a *Memberslist* section is rendered properly.

```
 it('renders MembersList', () => {
    const Component = withMemory(AdminAppCore, ROUTE_ADMIN_MEMBERS);
    const result = mount(
      <MockProvider stores={{ memberStore, programStore }}>
        <Component />
      </MockProvider>);
    expect(result.find(MembersList).length).toBe(1); // does not work :(.
```

Here is the code for AdminAppCore:

```
export const AdminAppCore = () => (
  <CacheHandler>
    {({ loading, isLatestVersion, refreshCacheAndReload }) => {
      if (loading) return null;
      if (!loading && !isLatestVersion) {
        refreshCacheAndReload();
      }
 
      return (
        <>
          <Route path={ROUTE_ADMIN_MEMBERS} render={() => <MembersList />} />
          //..other not important part
          //..other not important part
        </>
      );
    }}
  </CacheHandler>
);

export default withAppSkeleton(AdminAppCore, config);
```

Here is the problem. Inside of *AdminAppCore* is *Cachehandler*, which has in its constructor state *loading:true* and only after *componentDidMount* it changes to *loading:false*. As I have during mounting state loading:true, the Memberslist would not be rendered. What I tried was to make an async test that would wait until the state of loading will be true, so I tried something like this with enzyme-async-helpers:

```
  it.only('renders MembersList', async () => {
    const Component = withMemory(AdminAppCore, ROUTE_ADMIN_MEMBERS);
    const result = mount(
      <MockProvider children={{CacheHandler:loading=false}} stores={{ memberStore, programStore }}>
        <Component />
      </MockProvider>);
    console.log(result.debug());
    await waitForState(result, state => state.loading === false);
    expect(result.find(MembersList).length).toBe(1); 
    result.unmount();
  });
```

This will not work, because I have **fetch** inside of the  componentDidMount. So I get the *TypeError: Network request failed*

Here is part of the CacheHandler code:

```
class CacheHandler extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      isLatestVersion: false,
      refreshCacheAndReload: () => {
        if (caches) {
          caches.keys().then((names) => {
            names.forEach((name) => {
              caches.delete(name);
            })
          });
        }
        window.location.reload(true);
      }
    };
    this.metaPath = window.location.port === config.meta.port.LOCAL
      ? config.meta.path.LOCAL
      : config.meta.path.CONTAINER;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.metaPath)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((meta) => {
        const latestVersion = meta.version;
        const currentVersion = global.appVersion;

        const shouldForceRefresh = latestVersion !== currentVersion;
        if (shouldForceRefresh) {
          this.setState({ loading: false, isLatestVersion: false });
        } else {
          this.setState({ loading: false, isLatestVersion: true });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, isLatestVersion, refreshCacheAndReload } = this.state;
    return this.props.children({ loading, isLatestVersion, refreshCacheAndReload });
  }
}

CacheHandler.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default CacheHandler;
```

I need to mock the fetch which is inside of the componentDidMount, but I do not know how, everything I tried failed(I followed every tip for fetch mocking I found online). I spent  a lot of time on this problem and couldnt find out the right solution, I would appreciate any hint

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does this answer your question? [How to mock fetch when testing a React app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62405645/how-to-mock-fetch-when-testing-a-react-app). "everything I tried failed(I followed every tip for fetch mocking I found online" -- can you show your attempts specifically so I know exactly what's been tried so far? Otherwise, I'm stuck to reinvent all of your work from scratch and guess what you've tried. "I spent a lot of time on this problem and couldnt find out the right solution" doesn't really help me much -- specific code attempts do. Thanks.

Comment: Hello ggorlen, thanks a lot for your reply. This is amazing and embarassing at the same time, I have adjusted tip from the answer you sent and this part worked well for me, thank you! I dont know why I did not find it earlier...as I have this one, I will not post my trials before. Anyway, thank you for advice also regarding how to write questions, I will try to be more explanatory with what I already tried next time