# How to make an unit test for boolean value like 'loading' label?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

How to test a label that depends on a boolean variable to be rendered? For example, if the variable `isLoading` is true, then it will render `<p>Loading...</p>`.

I'm trying to test and I'm getting an error:

[image]

```
// AutoComplete.test.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import AutoComplete from './AutoComplete';

describe('AutoComplete component', () => {
  test('renders loading state when isLoading is true', () => {
    render(<AutoComplete />);
    const loadingElement = screen.getByText('Loading...');
    expect(loadingElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('renders "No countries found" when inputValue is at least 3 characters and searchResults is empty', () => {
    render(<AutoComplete />);
    const inputElement = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Search Country...');
    userEvent.type(inputElement, 'abc');
    const noCountriesElement = screen.getByText('No countries found');
    expect(noCountriesElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

```
// AutoComplete.tsx

import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { DataContext } from 'src/contexts';
import { Country } from 'src/types';
import Input from '../Input';
import './index.css';

const AutoComplete = () => {
  const { inputValue } = useContext(DataContext);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<Country[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  
  const fetchData = async (value: string) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://restcountries.com/v3/name/${value}`
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setSearchResults(data);
      } else {
        setSearchResults([]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const filterResults = useCallback(
    (results: Country[]) => {
      return results.filter((country) =>
        country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue)
      );
    },
    [inputValue]
  );
  
  const highlightSearchTerm = (text: string) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${inputValue})`, 'gi');    
    return text.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputValue && inputValue.length >= 3) {
      fetchData(inputValue);
    } else {
      setSearchResults([]);
    }
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Auto Complete</h1>
      <Input />

      <h2>Results: </h2>

      {isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : inputValue?.length >= 3 && searchResults.length === 0 ? (
        <p>No countries found</p>
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {filterResults(searchResults).map((country, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <h3
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: highlightSearchTerm(country.name.common),
                }}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AutoComplete;
```

Comment: `isLoading` starts as false, why _would_ "Loading..." be shown? Think about when the _user_ would see the loading message, and simulate that (i.e. not _"when isLoading is true"_ but from an end-user perspective).

Comment: Hi jonrsharpe, thank you for your help. Sorry, but I'm beginning on tests. Do u have some example on the internet where I can find something like that? Thank you

Comment: I've written [several blog posts](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Aug/31/js-tdd-ftw.html) on testing in JS, including a few with React/Testing Library. And look at https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro/. Fundamentally to test this you need to think about what it _does_ - it doesn't show a loading state when the component initially renders, it shows a loading state when the user has entered a few characters, so **do that** then try to assert on it, as you do in the other test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Loading...` text to appear on screen, you are goint to have to trigger the `fetchData` function, which is the one setting `isLoading` to `true`. You could do this by simulating user input and guaranteeing that the `fetch` function does not return any data.

```js
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

describe('AutoComplete component', async () => {
  test('renders loading state when isLoading is true', () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    const testText = "te"

    render(<AutoComplete />);


    // INFO: use the query that best suit your needs to access the input
    const autoCompleteInput = screen.getByLabelText(/input/i)

    await user.type(autocompleteInput, testText)

    const loadingElement = screen.getByText('Loading...');
    expect(loadingElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
})
```

I have not tested this code and I don't know if the `testing-library` will catch the text once it appears on screen but you will probably have to [mock fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62411174/11768882) for two reasons:

- Control that it takes some time to answer so `Loading...` has a chance to appear on the screen
- Isolate your test from the outside and control the autocomplete data (this is something you might want to do for every other test case, not just the one we're concerned here)